# Xcode and Objective-C++ can't find <cstdio>

Tags: c++, xcode, objective-c++

I'm writing Cocoa code that uses some classes defined in a C++ library.  I give the filename the extension .mm, and things are usually fine.

But not always.  Sometimes Xcode 4 disappoints me with: "Lexical or Preprocessor issue:  'cstdio' not found".   I can't figure out how to make Xcode find it.  Nor can I figure out why it works sometimes, but not others.  What do you think?

Edit:  Noise.   My filename extension was not .mm, but rather .m.   :(   There is not, and there never was, a problem.  See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It still should be able to find `<stdio.h>` just fine.

Edit: The .mm file should work fine all the time. Make sure in your build settings that `Compile Source As` is set to `According to File Type`

Comment: Indeed, I am used to rather opposite questions, like "what should I use instead of <stdio.h> in C++?" :-)

Comment: That might work, but in my case the call #include <cstdio>  is in the header for the C++ class that I'm using, and I don't own that code. I'm not anxious to change it if I can avoid it.

Comment: I updated the answer to check a build setting in your project. If your code file is .mm and that setting is correctly set it should work. You could also try setting it to build as Objective-C++ just to see if it works (would not recommend leaving it that way)

Comment: @#$%!  I must be going blind.  My filename extension was .m, not .mm. All is well, sorry about the noise.  Thanks all.